# "Find the access codes" Google Foobar challenge

Tags: python, list

I am currently working on the google foobar challenge, and was doing this task as follows:

> "Write a function answer(l) that takes a list of positive integers l and counts the number of "lucky triples" of (li, lj, lk) where the list indices meet the requirement i < j < k.
> The length of l is between 2 and 2000 inclusive. The elements of l are between 1 and 999999 inclusive.
> The answer fits within a signed 32-bit integer.
> Some of the lists are purposely generated without any access codes to throw off spies, so if no triples are found, return 0.
> A "lucky triple" is a tuple (x, y, z) where x divides y and y divides z, such as (1, 2, 4).
> For example, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] has the triples: [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 6], [1, 3, 6], making the answer 3 total."

I have wrote an attempt at it, resulting in this code:

```
def solution(input):
    count = 0
    tempList = []
    for _ in range(len(input)):
        value = input.pop()
        for item in input:
            if value % item == 0 and value >= item:
                tempList.append(item)
        combinations = itertools.combinations(tempList,2)
        for combination in combinations:
            if combination[1] % combination[0] != 0:
                continue
            count += 1
        tempList = []
    return(count)
```

This code was passing most test cases except for test case 5, however I have almost exhausted the tests to find out what fringe case was causing this issue, I have tested both test cases I manually wrote, and found a solution that works, and tried to use it with a randomiser to create new test cases and comparing them until I found the issue, I have however not found it yet.

I have originally used a code to display the combinations, but I went for this code because I suspected that the execution speed might've had something to do with it, however I am not sure if that's the issue, because even after minimising the code only one test case was giving me any faults.

I am expecting that I am missing some very silly case, I am mostly concerned in finding what the source of my issues with my code is in this case. Thank you.

**Edit:** I have been investigating delays, running basic timeit does show my solution is slower, but not siginficantly so. But regardless, I have ran additional delays in the working code, introducing significant enough delay that it should've tripped if that was the case. However it still works, leading me to believe I am missing something else here.

Comment: Your code seems correct. Just a (probably silly) idea, they may be thinking of _proper_ divisors (i.e. any positive number which divides a given number N, including 1 but excluding N itself), so your mistake would be counting a triple like [4,8,8] instead of ignoring it. But it is difficult to help without seeing the test case which fails

Comment: Unfortunately I can't say, I checked those, but apparently they need to be included. I am unable to check any more as the timing has passed, but I was quite curious about where I could've went wrong. But I agree that its probably some silly thing like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code could be just too slow to pass failing test case (runtime error or time limit exceeded errors are both tagged as simple fail in foobar).

Try altering the algorithm. You don't need to generate all the combinations for each element of the list. That gives you `O(n^3)` algorithm.

You can build `O(n^2)` algorithm by storing each possible pair for each element of array. Then simply traverse each pair, find possible triplets in `O(1)` and count them.

Example:
Consider following input `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. You can build map, which will hold the information about possible pairs for each element.

(Note: Elements in map are not elements from input, but their indexes)

```
map = {
    0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # Number at index 0 can pair with number at index 1, 2, 3 ....
    1: [3, 5]
    2: [5]
    3: [] # Number at index 3 can't pair with any other number
    4: []
    5: []
}
```

Now simply iterate through each pair in the map and count possible triplets for given pair. E.g. for `(0, 1)` there exists `len(map[1])` triplets. for `(0, 2)` there exists `len(map[2])` triplets. Giving you result `len(map[1]) + len(map[2]) == 3`.

(Note: Each other pair has 0 possible triplets. e.g. pair `(0, 3)` has `len(map[3])` triplets, which is 0. And you need to go through each possible pair in map)